# Compress and Extract options missing

Tags: desktop, filesystem

I definitely used to be able to select a set of files in File Manager and right-click >> "Compress" and pick the format (e.g. .tar.gz). I *think* I used to be able to right-click a compressed file and choose "Extract Here" or something like that but I'm not sure. Anyway, those options are now missing.

I think they disappeared when I uninstalled zip and unzip as per the suggestions here:
https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian

Since then I have reinstalled zip and unzip, but the menu options in File Manager have not returned. Any idea what I can do to be able to Compress, Extract from File Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those options are created when installing [Gnome Archive Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/FileRoller). It comes preisntalled with elementary OS. We can asume it's missing in your installation.

Try reinstalling it with `sudo apt install --reinstall file-roller`

Comment: Thanks! That did it! Not sure what I did to make it go away in the first place, but all good now!

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of elementaryOS 6, this reappeared for me, and the solution above didn't work; what did work was the following one: [Compress and Extract options missing from Files with latest update](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29165/compress-and-extract-options-missing-from-files-with-latest-update)

`sudo apt install --reinstall org.gnome.fileroller`

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall org.gnome.fileroller
```

Tested and works on Elementary OS 6.1 Jolnir

[image]

[image]