# Compress and Extract options missing from Files with latest update

Tags: files, odin

Just switched back to eOS to try eOS6, I've done two installs, and both times upon upgrading to the latest update, the Compress and Extract options are missing from right-click. Even double clicking on a zip file shows no apps that can decompress.

Tried re-installing file-roller, but that doesn't seem to integrated into the right-click menu, although I can now extract and compress manually using file-roller.

I suspect it is the latest update to Files. Has anything one encountered this, is there a fix currently?

Answer (score 4):

Managed to solve this. It seems this issue affects those who update via the terminal.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall org.gnome.fileroller
```

Comment: This was, indeed, my problem. I do updates with `sudo apt dist-upgrade` routinely, when AppCenter is acting flaky.